# HTML CSS hover not working

Tags: html, css

Today I was trying to achieve an animated icon, but I got in trouble with css. The upcomming code will say more than I can say:

```css
.Menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #35f5ca;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.title {
  font-family: "Sans-Serif";
  position: fixed;
  top: 1%;
  left: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: white;
}

.icon:hover {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.body {}
```

```html
<div class="Menu">
  <p1 class="title">
    <b>
 Mettu
 </b>
    <img class="icon" src="images/iconplanet.png" style="transition: all 0.5s; width:40px; height:40px; position:fixed; right: 5px; top: 0.5%; opacity: 0.5;" />
  </p1>
</div>

<div class="body">

</div>
```

Please don't just correct my code, and tell me what I did wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the style to the css, and .Menu should be .menu

```css
    .Menu
    {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #35f5ca;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
    }
    .title
    {
     font-family:"Sans-Serif";
     position:fixed;
     top: 1%;
     left: 0;
     vertical-align: middle;
     font-size: 150%;
     color: white;
    }
    .icon
    {
      transition: all 0.5s;
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
      position:fixed;
      right: 5px;
      top: 0.5%;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .icon:hover
    {
     width:45px; 
     height:45px; 
     position:fixed; 
     right: 0px; 
     top: 0px; 
     opacity: 1.0;
    }
    .body
    {
     
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head><title>Mettu</title>
    
    <head>
    <body>
    <div class="Menu">
    <p1 class="title">
     <b>
     Mettu
     </b>
     <img class="icon" src="images/iconplanet.png" />
    </p1>
    </div>

    <div class="body">

    </div>

    <?php
    //Menu


    //Menu's Brain


    ?>

    </body>

    <html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Style attributes are [more specific](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) any any rule-set.

If you have the same property in a rule-set with `.icon:hover` and in a style attribute, then the value in the style attribute will win.

Don't use the style attribute.